# Apply a function for all columns of a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor, stored-functions, dynamic-variables

I am trying to make a calculation in MySQL for all columns of a table.

Table: bev

```
Jahr     GKZ     gesamt A   B   C    
2017    1111000 88.519  855 888 814
2017    1112000 247.943 2.414   2.379   2.262
2017    1113000 253.106 2.290   2.343   2.289
2017    1113004 43.392  408 416 403
2017    1113008 12.383  137 134 124
2017    1113012 27.106  252 252 249
2017    1113016 41.673  391 410 398
2017    1113020 39.585  364 391 373
2017    1113024 10.075  63  73  74
2017    1113028 24.083  199 205 209
2017    1113032 8.745   63  77  65
2017    1113036 18.143  170 170 143
2017    1113040 27.921  243 215 251
```

Table: ja

```
GKZ  Jahr    ja_name
1001000 2017     K X
1002000 2017     K Y
5370000 2017     L Z
5370004 2017    Z1
5370012 2017    Z2
5370016 2017    Z3
5370020 2017    Z4
```

I already got the calculation for one column (the first one: gesamt) in a function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`DB`@`%` FUNCTION `Total_Amount_Funct`(
bev_ID int(11), 
bev_Total int(11), 
ja_name VARCHAR(255), 
ja_jahr int(11)) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE Total_Amount int(11);
    DECLARE kreis int(11);
    DECLARE Total_Sum int(11); 

    SET kreis = (bev_ID / 1000) ;
    SET Total_Sum = (SELECT  SUM(b.gesamt)
        FROM bev as b, ja as j
        WHERE b.GKZ = j.GKZ 
        AND b.Jahr = j.Jahr    
        AND j.Jahr = ja_jahr
        AND (MOD(b.GKZ, 1000) <> 0)
        AND (MOD(b.GKZ, 1000) != 0)
        AND NOT (MOD(b.GKZ, 1000) = 0)
        AND (b.GKZ BETWEEN (kreis*1000 + 1) AND (((kreis+1)*1000)-1))
        AND j.ja_name IS NOT NULL);

    SET Total_Amount = bev_Total-Total_Sum;       

    RETURN (Total_Amount);
END
```

This function can be called with the following select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    bev.GKZ,
    bev.Jahr,
    bev.gesamt,
CASE WHEN (bev.GKZ % 1000 = 0) THEN
    coalesce(Total_Amount_Funct(bev.GKZ, bev.gesamt, ja.ja_name, bev.Jahr), bev.gesamt)
    ELSE bev.gesamt
END AS bev,
    ja.ja_name
FROM
    ja, bev
WHERE
    bev.GKZ = ja.GKZ
AND bev.Jahr = ja.Jahr;
```

I really would like to apply the function for all columns of the table. Maybe as a stored procedure? Maybe as dynamic columns. I do not know. I have solved this problem in MS SQL with dynamic columns but I have the feeling that translating it will take more time than trying to complete the function as a Stored Procedure.

The name of the columns can be obtained by:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='bev'
and column_name  not in ('Jahr','GKZ');
```

As Result it should be:

```
GKZ  Jahr    gesamt  bev     ja_name    
1111000 2017    88.519  88.519   K X    
1112000 2017    247.943 247.943  K Y    
1113000 2017    253.106 101.350  L Z    
1113004 2017    43.392  43.392  Z1    
1113012 2017    27.106  27.106  Z2    
1113016 2017    41.673  41.673  Z3    
1113020 2017    39.585  39.585  Z4
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the column only in the SUM, you could pass the column name as parameter and use CASE-statement to pick the column accordingly. Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `Total_Amount_Funct`(
bev_ID decimal(8,3), 
bev_Total int, 
ja_name VARCHAR(255), 
ja_jahr int,
in_col varchar(10)
) 
RETURNS int
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE Total_Amount int(11);
    DECLARE Total_Sum int(11); 

    SELECT  
      SUM(
       case 
        when in_col='gesamt' then b.gesamt 
        when in_col='A' then b.A 
        when in_col='B' then b.B 
        when in_col='C' then b.C
       end
      ) into Total_Sum
      FROM bev as b
        join ja as j on b.GKZ = j.GKZ AND b.Jahr = j.Jahr    
      WHERE 
        MOD(b.GKZ, 1000) != 0
        AND b.GKZ BETWEEN bev_ID+1 AND bev_ID+999
        AND j.ja_name IS NOT NULL

    SET Total_Amount = bev_Total-Total_Sum;       

    RETURN (Total_Amount);
END
```

And then call the function with column name and correct value:

```
Total_Amount_Funct(bev.GKZ, bev.gesamt, ja.ja_name, bev.Jahr, 'gesamt'),
Total_Amount_Funct(bev.GKZ, bev.A, ja.ja_name, bev.Jahr, 'A')
...
```

Note that calling a function which makes a query will serialize your SQL (calling the function on each row causes the function query to be executed on each row). This will hurt the query performance.

Answer (score 0):

slaakso,

thank you very much for your answer. You are from today my idol :-).

Thanks Thanks.

I have maybe one performance Question.

It is posible to write the function for all columns of the table bev. We can copy the column names in a temporary table:

```
  CREATE  TEMPORARY TABLE listColumns(
        Columns_ID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        Columnsnamen varchar(256) ,
         PRIMARY KEY (Columns_ID)
    );
```

Readed from the System Information:

```
    insert into listColumns (Columnsnamen)
    SELECT column_name 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name='bev'
    and column_name  not in ('Jahr','GKZ');
```

This Table looks like:

```
Columns_ID  Columnsnamen
1           gesamt
2           A
3           B
4           C
5   
6
```

In such a way, that it is not necessary to mentione every column name (the table contains about 100 columns). Maybe with a cursor over the Columns_ID?

It woul be great if you have another advice for me.

Thank you and kind regads

Ana

Comment: If you have a table with 100 columns, you probably should take a look at your table structure. If your table contains columns like value1, value2, ... valueN, you should put the values in separate table. If you try to create a temp table with dynamic information from information_schema, you have a high chance digging a deeper hole to yourself. You could show your table structure and put the question as a new question into Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi, I think I did not express well my sentence. I am using the temporal table just for colecting the column names in order to make it more accesible. Your suggestion for the problem above was to use a case SELECT  
      SUM(
       case 
        when in_col='gesamt' then b.gesamt 
        when in_col='A' then b.A 
        when in_col='B' then b.B 
        when in_col='C' then b.C
       end
      ) into Total_Sum                                               My Idea woul be tu substitute it with a dinamical select over all the columns with @ or with for. Do you understand my issue? BR

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by 100 columns nor what you are trying to do with all those columns. You should show your real table structure. The table in your question had 6 columns.

Comment: I am Trying to apply the function above for every column of a table. Your suggestion was to write SELECT  
      SUM(case when in_col='gesamt' then b.gesamt 
        when in_col='A' then b.A 
        when in_col='B' then b.B 
        when in_col='C' then b.C
       end ) into Total_Sum
      FROM bev as b .....
      
    SET Total_Amount = bev_Total-Total_Sum;       
    RETURN (Total_Amount);
In the example I used just 4 columns. gesamt, A, B and C. But there are much more. Ideal would be something like

Comment: for i in column SUM(Column_i) into Total_Sum_i
FROM bev as b .....
SET Total_Amount_i= bev_Total_i - Total_Sum_i; 
RETURN (Total_Amount_i);                                                                                                i representing that the funtion is beeing used dynamical over all the 100 columns of the table bev. That is the reason why I put all this column names in the temporal Table. Do you understand? BR Ana

Comment: You really should reconsider your table structure before going any further. Having the values in a separate table rather than 100 columns in one table would allow for you to solve your problems wihout any hassle.

Comment: What do you mean with "Having the values in a separate table rather than 100 columns in one table" at the moment I have the Table bev, which hat following structure.                                                                                                             
 GKZ  Jahr    gesamt  bev     ja_name     A B C D ........X Y Z ...
1111000 2017    88.519  88.519   K X    
The claculation has to be made for every column of the table, gesamt, A, B, C, ..., X, Y, Z,.... With the case solution I have to mention every colunm name and it would be great to say: "for every column in table"

Comment: Assuming GKZ+Jahr is the primary key for the table, instead of having a table "GKZ Jahr A B C D ........X Y", you should have a second table bev_values with columns "GKZ Jahr letter value" where the letter would represent the columns "A B C D ........X Y" and value the value of it. Then leave out the columns "A B C D ........X Y" from the bev-table.